# javascript .click() no work in chrome driver

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, google-chrome, webdriver

this is my code:

```
String script = "document.getElementById('"+Sendcontrol+"').click();";
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript(script);
```

but it show

> Script execution failed.has no method 'click'

So,how can I solve this problem?

Comment: what exactly are u trying to achieve? trigger a click on SendControl?

Comment: yes actually I want to locate the control by javascript and find it by ID in the webpage. And click the controls (ex. button)

Comment: `click()` is a method of jQuery. `getElementById` will not return a jQuery object, but a DOM object, which has no `click()` method.

Comment: oh,i see. thank u .so how can I modify the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `onclick()`, instead of `click()`.

[document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) method returns [DOM Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element), which does not have `"click"` method you were trying to call.

Comment: Script execution failed. is not a function @@ why?

Comment: @Edison `document.getElementById('"+Sendcontrol+"').onclick();` will work on javascript. Why it fails on `ExecuteScript` call, I can't say. I am not familiar with `C#`.

Answer (score -1):

Error is rather self-explanatiory. In chrome not every arbitrary element has method `click`.